# Not able to iterate data using scrapy in python

Tags: python, scrapy, screen-scraping

I am scraping below website for Actress name ,rank and score 
http://www.timescelebex.com/top_actresses

i could able to get 1 record but cannot iterate with for look for rest of the records

I could able to receive data like below but for only 1 record

{'Score': u'41.0', 'Name': u'Deepika Padukone', 'Rank': u'1'}

i want to extract like above for all records

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class ActressListSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'actress_list'
    allowed_domains = ['timescelebex.com/top_actresses']
    start_urls = ['http://timescelebex.com/top_actresses/']

    def parse(self, response):
        names=response.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/section/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody')

        for name in names:
            actress = name.xpath('//*[@class="Droid Ctxt1"]/text()').extract_first()
            rank = name.xpath('//*[@class="Droid Stext"]/text()').extract_first()
            score = name.xpath('//*[@class="Stext2"]/text()').extract_first()

            yield{'Name':actress,'Rank':rank,'Score':score}
```

if i use .extract instead of .extract_first() i could see all data but its coming in like below

{'Score': , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ]>, 'Name': , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ]>, 'Rank': , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ]>}

Comment: all scores coming in 1 line , all names coming in 1 line and all Ranks coming in 1 line... with the use of extract() method. i want  score,actress,rank for each record like this....     {'Score': u'41.0', 'Name': u'Deepika Padukone', 'Rank': u'1'}

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **relative** XPath inside `for` loop:

```
def parse(self, response):
    names=response.xpath('//table[@class="ITable"]//table//tr[position() > 2]')

    for name in names:
        actress = name.xpath('.//*[@class="Droid Ctxt1"]/text()').extract_first()
        rank = name.xpath('.//*[@class="Droid Stext"]/text()').extract_first()
        score = name.xpath('.//*[@class="Stext2"]/text()').extract_first()

        yield{'Name':actress,'Rank':rank,'Score':score}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this XPath to get all the wanted selectors:

```
names = response.xpath('//td[@width="35%"]//tr[td[contains(@class, "Droid")]]')
```

This will select all rows with actresses (skipping the table header) from the first table (Jan 2018). Then you can iterate over the `names` list of selectors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Css Version

```
def parse(self, response):
        names=response.css('tr')

        for name in names:
            actress = name.css('td.Droid.Ctxt1::text').extract_first()
            rank = name.css('td.Droid.Stext::text').extract_first()
            score = name.css('td.Stext2::text').extract_first()

            yield{'Name':actress,'Rank':rank,'Score':score}
```